# How do I vertically join or merge multiple datasets within R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, concatenation, rbind

I have 12 datasets that all resemble this (this is a sample, the real datasets all contain over 10,000 varying rows, with the same number/name of columns)

```
   df1

   Start                End                      Duration

   9/10/2019 1:00:00  PM  9/10/2019 1:00:10  PM   10
   10/10/2019 2:00:00 PM 10/10/2019 2:00:10  PM   10


   df2

   Start                End                        Duration

   11/10/2019 1:00:00 AM  11/10/2019 1:00:10  AM   10
   12/10/2019 2:00:00 AM  12/10/2019 2:00:10  AM   10


    df3

   Start                   End                   Duration

   01/10/2020 1:00:00 AM   01/10/2020 1:00:10 AM   10
   02/10/2020 2:00:00 AM   02/10/2020 2:00:10 AM   10
```

I would like this outcome:

```
   Start                     End                   Duration

   9/10/2019  1:00:00 PM    9/10/2019 1:00:10  PM   10
   10/10/2019 2:00:00 PM    10/10/2019 2:00:10 PM   10
   11/10/2019 1:00:00 AM    11/10/2019 1:00:10 AM   10
   12/10/2019 2:00:00 AM    12/10/2019 2:00:10 AM   10
   01/10/2020 1:00:00 AM    01/10/2020 1:00:10 AM   10
   02/10/2019 2:00:00 AM    02/10/2019 2:00:10 AM   10
```

Here is my dput:

```
 structure(list(Start = structure(1:2, .Label = c("11/10/2019 13:00", 
 "12/10/2019 14:00"), class = "factor"), End = structure(1:2, .Label = c("11/10/2019 13:00", 
 "12/10/2019 14:00"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(10L, 10L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))



 structure(list(Start = structure(1:2, .Label = c("11/10/2019 1:00:00 AM", 
 "12/10/2019 2:00:00 AM"), class = "factor"), End = structure(1:2, .Label = c("11/10/2019 1:00:10 AM", 
"12/10/2019 2:00:10 AM"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(10L, 
 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


 structure(list(Start = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/10/2020 1:00:00 AM", 
 "2/10/2020 2:00:00 AM"), class = "factor"), End = structure(1:2, .Label =     c("1/10/2020 1:00:10 AM", 
 "2/10/2020 2:00:10 AM"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(10L, 
 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
  combined <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

However, it only works when joining 2 datasets and not 10

Comment: We can use `do.call(rbind, lst1)` Place the datsets in a list.  `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")))`

Comment: your `dput` data doesn't include all the rows that you want in your output. It would be a lot easier to test solutions if the full output was there.

Comment: ok I will add the other 2 dput

Comment: ok @akrun, I do not understand where I would put the dataset names in?  So I would type out:    do.call(rbind, lst1) and then do.call(rbind, mget(lst1(pattern = "df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6")  ???

Comment: If you have created objects name as `df1`, `df2` etc.  the above code would work i.e. pattern = "^df\\d+$"`

Comment: Please check the output of `mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$"))` it will be all of the data.frames that created in a list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [bind_rows](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html) trom the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
dim(mtcars) # [1] 32 11
BindMtcars <- bind_rows(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
dim(BindMtcars) # [1] 128  11
```

Comment: Ok will this bind multiple different datasets together? There are 12 labeled df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df...

Comment: Yes, just do bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, ...df12)

Comment: I was able to do rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6), but I found out that bind_rows does the same thing. (regardless of column #)